# How to disable Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have an HTC One, and I went to `Settings -> Apps -> All` to disable a few apps I didn't want on my phone (7digital, Facebook, Google Play Music, Google+). The apps are now gone and the update notifications disapeared for these apps in Google Play.

But for some reason Hangouts is not there. How can I disable it?

Comment: Did you even have Hangouts in the first place?

Comment: I managed to disable it. You need to remove all Hangouts updates in Google Play, then reboot for Hangouts to go back to Talk, then Talk can be disabled in Settings -> Apps -> All.

Comment: You might want to add this fix as an answer and toggle it as the correct one.

Comment: I couldn't. I got a message saying you can't reply to your own question before 8 hours when you have under 10 rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phone came with Google Talk, then Google forced the update to Google Hangouts.

You need to remove all Hangouts updates in Google Play, then reboot and Hangouts will disappear from the application list and Talk be back. Talk can then be disabled in `Settings -> Apps -> All`.

Comment: My phone (Samsung Note 3), came with Hangouts installed. The process was similar, however. Disabling the app automatically uninstalled the updates, reducing it to an old version of Hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

On android kitkat: long click on the hangout app and drag it to app info. Click on turn off.

To enable the app again: go to home, press menu (bottom)/ select manage app /go to tab: turn off